# getJSON function is skipped in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

Hello I have the following code:

```
listItems.forEach( item =>  {


        $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=KS_Vw5DMlEI&key=AIzaSyAlUj6YMmrt-0s34dQ-LdywneUzZhmsVYA', function(data) {
                                                                                                    
       const viewsin = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount; 
       localStorage.setItem('ViewsCounter3', viewsin );
       alert('inside: ' + viewsin);
                                                                                    
        });

       alert('outside: ' + localStorage.getItem('ViewsCounter3'));

});
```

My problem is this: Neither every pass in my foreach loop, the code outside the getJSON function is executed first and then the code in the function.  The order of the alerts looked like this:

```
                "outside: View Count", "inside: View Count", "outside: View Count", etc...
```

I would like to have the inside alert executed first and then the outside alert when it is finished. I already tried await but this did not work, because I think it is an asynchronous function.

Is there a way to keep the code running after the code has been executed in the getJSOn function?

Could someone please help me with my problem. I would be happy about answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` loop doesn't work for defining an async step. Try `for...of` loop with `await`

```
for(let item of listItems){
  await $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=KS_Vw5DMlEI&key=AIzaSyAlUj6YMmrt-0s34dQ-LdywneUzZhmsVYA')
    .done(data=>{                                                                                             
       const viewsin = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount; 
       localStorage.setItem('ViewsCounter3', viewsin );
       alert('inside: ' + viewsin);                                                                          
    });
    alert('outside: ' + localStorage.getItem('ViewsCounter3'));
};
```